# Intersection of affine open subsets can be covered by opens that looks like a certain form

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I suspect that this is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597925/u-1-cap-u-2-can-be-covered-by-open-sets-which-are-basic-in-both-u-1-and-u?noredirect=1&lq=1) problem, but as I do not understand scheme yet, I am looking for an elementary solution.

Let $X$ be a prevariety, and let $U, V$ be affine open subsets. Prove that $U \cap V$ can be covered by open subsets which are each simultaneously of the form $U \setminus Z(f)$ for $f \in A(U)$ and $V \setminus Z(g)$ for $g \in A(V)$.

I guess we can pick an open neighbourhood for each $x \in U \cap V$, but I am not sure on how to pick a good $f$ both in $A(U)$ and $A(V)$. Based on the link, I am thinking something $f / g^k$ for some $f,g$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You don't actually need to understand anything about schemes to apply the same solution here - you can think only in terms of functions and their nonvanishing sets.

Comment: I am reading the solution by user27126 in the linked thread, and I have several questions. First, he/she writes $x \in D_U(f) \subset U \cap V$. I assume that $D_U(f)$ is the set of points that in $U$ that do not vanish in $f$. Why we can fix that it is must inside $U \cap V$? Secondly, does the last line essentialy says that because $D_U(f) \subset V$, we can just restrict from $D_V(g)$ to $D_{D_U(f)}(g|_{D_U(f)})$? Thanks! @KReiser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know that the open sets of the form $D_U(f):=U\setminus Z(f)$ form a basis for the topology of $U$ (and similarly for $V$). Now take $x\in U\cap V$, and as $U\cap V\subseteq U$ is open, there exists $f$ such that $x\in D_U(f)\subseteq U\cap V$. Now the trick is to apply now the same reasoning to $D_U(f)\subseteq V$: there exists $g$ such that $x\in D_V(g)\subseteq D_U(f)$.

Now we have the restriction morphism $\mathcal{O}_X(V)\to\mathcal{O}_X(D_U(f))=\mathcal{O}_X(U)_f$, so $g$ is mapped to some $a/f^{m}$ for $a\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$. As a short intermezzo, note that if we have open sets $W\subseteq W'$ and $h\in\mathcal{O}_X(W')$, them
$$
D_{W}(h|_{W})=W\cap D_{W'}(h).
$$
Now the important thing to notice is
$$
D_U(af)=D_U(a)\cap D_U(f)=D_{D_U(f)}(a|_{D_U(f)})=D_{D_U(f)}(a/f^m)=D_{D_U(f)}(g|_{D_U(f)})=\\
=D_U(f)\cap D_V(g)=D_V(g).
$$
Hence $D_V(g)$ is also distinguished open inside $U$, so we are done.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! To check, in the final line, should it be $D_U(gf)$ instead? As from my understanding, $g$ restricted to $D_U(f)$ is $a/f^m$.

Comment: You're welcome! No I actually meant $D_U(af)$; note that $D_U(gf)$ isn't well-defined because $g$ isn't a function on $U$. The $a$ is precisely there to cook up a function on $U$ which has the same non-vanishing as $g$, which is a function on $V$.

Comment: I see, so the step in the third equality is because on $D_U(f)$, the zero set of $a$ (restricted to $D_U(f)$) and $a/f^m$ is the same?

Comment: Exactly, because $1/f^m$ is a unit on $D_U(f)$ so it doesn't vanish anywhere.