# Finding a distinguished open set in the intersection of two $\operatorname{Spec}$s

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

I am trying to follow the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/384137/120503) about an intersection of affine open sets being covered by affine open sets.  However, I can't seem to figure out why given $\operatorname{Spec} A \cap \operatorname{Spec} B$, it is possible to find a distinguished open set $D_{A}(f) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} A \cap \operatorname{Spec} B$.  How would one show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is open, as is $\operatorname{Spec} B$, so their intersection $\operatorname{Spec} A \cap \operatorname{Spec} B$ is again open. This means that the complement of $\operatorname{Spec} A \cap \operatorname{Spec} B$ inside either $\operatorname{Spec} A$ or $\operatorname{Spec} B$ is closed in that particular affine patch, and therefore one may pick a function $f$ which is zero on it and take $D_A(f)$.